# logrotate doesn't seems to work as expected

Tags: logging, log-files, syslog, rsyslog

Below is my log rotation configuration for /var/log/messages.

```
/var/log/messages
{
    rotate 4
    size 100M
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
    ifconfig eth0 | grep 'Device not found' &>/dev/null
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
      kill -HUP $(cat /var/run/rsyslog.pid) > /dev/null
    else
      kill -HUP $(cat /var/run/rsyslog_1.pid) > /dev/null
    fi
    endscript
}
```

I ended up in a scenario where logrotate created messages.1 where my previous logs are copied and rsyslog is still writing into messages.1 (might be because of **delaycompress**). Now messages file is created newly when log rotation happened it is of size Zero.

Since I have huge logging enabled for my application and rsyslog is still writing into messages.1, it became more than 3G while messages file being zero.

Any wrong with my configurations or do i need to enable/disable certain logrotate features to never end up in this kind of scenario ?

```
# logrotate --version 
logrotate 3.8.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Try manually if such command line youre using actually reloads rsyslog. Test it by renaming messages to messages.x and touch messages plus chmod/chown it to same permissions as messages originally and then run this kill command, see if rsyslog actually starts using new file. If not, perhaps something wrong with that command. Is pid correct in such pidfile? Is pidfile present at all?

Anyhow, few more to try, debian uses these for example:

```
systemctl kill -s HUP rsyslog.service
invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate
```

And ofcourse, to debug logrotate, there is

```
logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.conf
```

which could possibly indicate some issues with logrotate config.

In the end, there is some kind of simple debugging, to see what gets executed:

```
...
postrotate
echo "before ifconfig" >> /tmp/logrotate.debug
ifconfig eth0 | grep 'Device not found' &>/dev/null
echo "after ifconfig" >> /tmp/logrotate.debug
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
  echo "inside if" >> /tmp/logrotate.debug
  kill -HUP $(cat /var/run/rsyslog.pid) > /dev/null
else
  echo "inside else" >> /tmp/logrotate.debug
  kill -HUP $(cat /var/run/rsyslog_1.pid) > /dev/null
fi
echo "at endscript" >> /tmp/logrotate.debug
endscript
...
```